# How do I convert a 4-digit julian date(yDDD) into a calendar date format like MM/dd/yyy using java?

Tags: java

Input - Julian Date - "7107"
Output - Calendar Date 
I tried the following code

```
String julianDate = "7107";
SimpleDateFormat fmt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yDDD");
Date date = fmt1.parse(julianDate);
SimpleDateFormat fmt2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String output = fmt2.format(date);
System.out.println("Calendar Date : " + output);
```

But getting wrong output as "Calendar Date : 04/17/0007"

So since folks ask how that single "7" represent year. So even if I give "2017107" as input, representing "YYYYDDD" format . Even then I am getting wrong output.

My expected output for "2017107" julian date is "04/17/2017" .But output is Calendar Date : 11/01/0048

Used Java 7 version

Comment: What date should 7107 be? `yDDD` would mean year 7 and day 107 in that year which is April 17th (day 107 in a non-leapyear) of the year 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Julian Date to Regular Calendar Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017954/convert-a-julian-date-to-regular-calendar-date)

Comment: if java 8 you can use code described in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36716991/4664558

Comment: what is the date you actually expected?

Comment: @InjuredThePatient No, you linked to a Question dealing with "Julian" that means a count of days since -4713-11-24 Gregorian. I suspect this Question is about day-of-year, 1-366 (a common misuse of the term "Julian").

Comment: @BasilBourque I see. Jala Lakshmi which Java version is used here ?

Comment: By “yDDD", do you mean a single digit for year and three digits for day-of-year 1-366? If so, how do your translate that single digit to a year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyD").parse("2017107");
```

Date `getYear()` is deprecate now.

Use this way to get year,

```
int year = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(date));
```

Comment: Thanks Kushan. The output is correct for this loc, but to get in "MM/dd/YYYY" format if I use date.getYear() then its giving wrong output . date.getYear() gives 117.

Answer (score 0):

## Ordinal date

The technical term for describing a date as a year and a day-of-year (1-366) is [*Ordinal Date*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date).

Define your formatting pattern using uppercase `D` for day-of-year 1-366.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuDDD" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2017107" , f );
```

Generate a string in that format.

```
String output = ld.format( f );
```

## ISO 8601

I suggest sticking to the “expanded” format standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Ordinal_dates) format if at all possible: YYYY-DDD such as `2017-107`. You are using the “basic” version of the standard format which is less readable and less obvious than the expanded version.

## Back-port

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

## Extensions

Tip: You may find helpful the `DayOfYear` class in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project when you move to Java 8 or 9. That project extends the java.time classes to add functionality.

Comment: Thanks Bourque. But I am using Java 7. DateTimeFormatter and LocalDate are not supported in it.

Comment: Uh, questioner is using Java 7 -- wasn't DateTimeFormatter introduced in Java 8?

Comment: @JohnHascall  Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Well worth the bother of adding a library to your project, as the legacy date-time classes are an awful mess.